# Dissolve spatio temporal data with GeoPandas without missing the temporal part

Tags: python, geopandas, dissolve, spatio-temporal-data

I am wondering if there's a clever way to use the [`dissolve()`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.dissolve.html) method of GeoPandas with a spatio temporal geodataframe without losing the temporal part.

I have a dataset where for different days of the year the same geometries could repeat. I need to aggregate (dissolve) these geometries by ID but I need to do it for each day.

My geodataframe looks like this:

```
geometry DATE ID VOL
POINT 2020-01-01 1 100
POINT 2020-01-01 1 50
POINT 2020-01-01 2 50
POINT 2020-01-01 2 50
POINT 2020-01-02 1 70
POINT 2020-01-02 1 40
POINT 2020-01-02 2 30
POINT 2020-01-02 2 70
...
```

My desired output should be:

```
geometry DATE ID VOL
MULTIPOINT 2020-01-01 1 150
MULTIPOINT 2020-01-01 2 100
MULTIPOINT 2020-01-02 1 110
MULTIPOINT 2020-01-02 2 100
```

With `gdf.dissolve(by='ID', aggfunc='sum')` the result is missing the temporal information, and I understand why, but, is there a way I can aggregate preserving it?

```
geometry ID VOL
MULTIPOINT 1 260
MULTIPOINT 2 200
```

Here is the code in order to replicate the test:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

d = {
    'geometry': [Point(1,2), Point(2,1), Point(3,4), Point(4,3),
                 Point(1,2), Point(2,1), Point(3,4), Point(4,3)],
    'DATE': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01',
             '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02'],
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'VOL': [100, 50, 50, 50, 70, 40, 30, 70 ]
}

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")
dissolved = gdf.dissolve(by='ID', aggfunc='sum')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the last line as:

```
dissolved = gdf.dissolve(by=['DATE', 'ID'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   DATE         ID  geometry               VOL
0  2020-01-01   1   MULTIPOINT (1 2, 2 1)  150
1  2020-01-01   2   MULTIPOINT (3 4, 4 3)  100
2  2020-01-02   1   MULTIPOINT (1 2, 2 1)  110
3  2020-01-02   2   MULTIPOINT (3 4, 4 3)  100
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Ehi, thanks again for the answer. I had the opportunity to run the dissolve command against my real dataset (>3 millions of records). All the commands I run like read, merge, sjoin take some seconds to finish. The dissolve hangs indefinitely (so far, I wasn't able to see it ending...). I really don't know why, might be an index issue? (maybe I will dig more into it, but if you already had similar issues please let me know if you can.

Comment: I tested the script on a small dataset. Check these searches: [geopandas+spatial+index](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=geopandas+spatial+index), [geopandas+dissolve](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=geopandas+dissolve).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I ended up separating the spatial and temporal parts. This way, I can dissolve my geometries once and not as many times as the days in a year, making my dataset much lighter (i.e, 7893 records, against 4478913). Yeah, it was probably too much for dissolve to handle it in a relatively small amount of time ;) Your answer still remains correct of course and very much appreciated and I will use it (a lot!).